# Detect if page is inside of an iframe and get iframe id

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

We have a game and one of our clients is attempting to load the game inside of their iframe. For some reason they need the address bar locked and have added the scrolling="no" style to their iFrame.

This breaks our game as we have a scroll up overlay that they can never get rid of.

I'm looking for a way to get the iframe and check the iframe id without needing a cross domain policy on their domain. Is this possible. All I need is the iframeID or maybe check the style and see if its scrollable.

I feel like this is not possible due to browser crossdomain security but figured id ask here and see if anyone has any suggestions.

Im attempting this.

```
var ganFrame = document.getElementById( ganId );
```

which returns null which it should

calling

```
var ganFrame = window.top.getElementById( ganId );
```

but I get the crossdomain error which is expected. Is there a way to detect this iframe without an error. I do not need access to it just a way to see if it exists.

I can detect if window.top != window.self but we have other clients who need us in a iframe with the overlay.

**Note**

*client will not change how their iframe behaves.*

Comment: Wait. The iframe is 100 width and height, and is basically unescapable? And you're trying to fix it with JavaScript?

Comment: No it fits in the window. we just have an overlay that requires the user to swipe up on the screen. Because their iframe is not scrollable this code does not work.

We just want to hide the overlay in this case but cannot detect their iframe.

Comment: I realize a crossDomain.xml policy is the way to go but if we can avoid that then that would be better.

Comment: There has to be a way to detect it. Is the iframe visible in the code? Is it a browser or an app or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> client will not change how their iframe behaves.

Would your client be willing to change the url to your game?
You could for example let them pass a parameter in the url like:
https://mygame.com/game.php?noScrollMode=true

You could check if document.referrer is set, but users might disable the referrer and break your code.

Comment: While this would work, in the past they have been very reluctant to accommodate us and make changes. We have in game promotions and offers and use a url Parameter for that and for the sole reason of this client we had to default it to off as they refused to change their end.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack but it solved my issue.

So because I know the id of the frame I'm looking for I'm able to use this code to get the desired effect.

```
if(window.top != window.self){
    try {
        var ganFrame = window.top.getElementById("gameFrame");
    }
    catch ( e ) {
        isIOS7HelperDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

just hoping no other errors get triggered from this. Might need to check the error type.

Comment: This solution does not work. if you call any method of window.top is gives a crossdomain error.